# It's possible to grab javascript variable from an external HTML file with PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Is it possible to use `PHP` to get a `Javascript` variable from an external `html` file?

In the case, I would like to get the `var` `src:`

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
                var sources = [{
                    type: "video/mp4",
                    src: "https://cdn.example.mp4",
                    res: "Trailer",
                    label: "Trailer"
                }];
                etc.
    </script>
```

Comment: You may want to do some ajax call, and give to your php script the data with the POST method

Comment: do you got any understandable reason why not to put all your js code inside external js file and than load this file into php where ever you need it ?

Comment: @x-magix Because the js code is inside an html file

Comment: @bpy hmm so create new jsFile.js and put all of the code in it. Then load it <script src="jsFile.js" type="text/javascript" /> in every php where you need it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there are **better** ways.

But here is a simple method:

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents("path to javascript");

//Remove everything before the string
$src = substr($content, strpos($content, "src: \"")+6, 100);

//Remove everything after the string
$src = substr($src, 0, strpos($src, "\""));
?>
```

Comment: What is the response from the file_get_contents()? Of you do     var_dump($content);

Answer (score -1):

I do not quite understand your question, but hopefully, this will help.

```
// source.js
var mySource = {

  type: "video/mp4",
  src: "https://cdn.example.mp4",
  res: "Trailer",
  label: "Trailer"

};
```

In your main file e.g index.php

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="source.js"></script>
```

Then use it like this:

```
<video width="320" height="240" autoplay>
  <source src="mySource.src" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```